# Can I get the sum() using entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ajax, entity-framework

I want to calculate the sum of a column
***note that***:column result showed as column in a table produced by calling stored proc with entity framework and AJAX

The code below show **Web method** that call the stored proc called **divideTypes**

```
if (ddlTer == "0")
    {

        var sp = db.divideTypes(dateFrom, dateTo, ddlType).ToList();
        foreach (var u in sp)
        {
            result += "<tr>";
            result += "<td>" + u.custid + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.custname + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.depno + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.Terr + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.deidate + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.gooddesc + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.custdec + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.pkg + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.wt + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.vwt + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.lcamt+ "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.invno + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.invamt + "</td>";
            result += "</tr>";
        }

    }
```

**Note:** I used to call stored proc because there's many join statement in SQL command so I cannot deal with it.

**My question is how to get the sum of u.invmat column? (In any way)**

Comment: It is very unclear what you need exactly? consider editing question and including some details .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the `Sum` method:

```
var sum = sp.Sum(d=>d.u.invmant);
```

Comment: thank you very much